# Fluent NHibernate with ASP.NET MVC 2 - Session management with 1 connection string per user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, session, fluent-nhibernate

I need to configure my Fluent NHibernate / ASP.NET MVC 2 application to use a single connection/connection string for each user.  This is because:

1. There are multiple databases, all with the same schema, that the user can choose to log into.
2. The legacy application, with which this ASP.NET app works in tandem, is based on the DB vendor's platform and therefore insists on using DB user accounts.
3. Trying to convince the DBA to provide a single do-everything user account would be even more painful and time consuming than just figuring out how to make it work.

I feel I have to explain my reasons in order to avoid several "Don't do that" answers.

So anyway, I first set everything up the normal, correct way with a single connection string.  I used an LLBLGen-created `SessionManager` to create a `SessionFactory`.  The `SessionFactory` gets created and stored during `Application_Start()`.  I also have an `IHttpModule` that binds the NHibernate session to the current session context.  (I forget whose website I got that from).

What I now **want** to do is have the users arrive at a login page.  They will choose their database and enter a username and password.  The application will create a database connection, store it in the user's session, and NHibernate will pick up that database connection and use it.

Any tips about doing this in general would be very helpful, but really I need to just get over the initial hurdles:  If I remove the DB connection info from the `SessionFactory` configuration, it complains and throws an exception.  If I don't remove the DB connection info from the SessionFactory configuration, it seems to use that connection string even when provided a different connection using `OpenSession(IDbConnection)`.  Also, now that I don't even want NHibernate to do anything until the user has logged in, I feel like my `IHttpModule` may be causing some of these problems.

Apologies if this sounds more like an incoherent rant than a question; I've just been banging my head against the wall for a while now.  Any and all suggestions on best practices (other than "Use one connection string, idiot!") are appreciated.

Comment: My don't do that answer would be (besides getting a new DBA): don't store a connection object (or any object with memory footprint or disposable object) in the session. Your solution sounds very complex for this problem.

Comment: What about storing `SessionFactory`s in the session?  I know they're fairly expensive to create, but am I asking for trouble by creating and storing one in the session when the user logs in?

Comment: Storing the sessionfactory in the session saves you the effort of manually managing the ado.net connection pool, overriding opening and closing connections, but it sounds easier to hard code a dictionary of usernames and sessionfactories in a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NHibernateMultipleDBs.aspx? It doesn't explain how to do this with Fluent, rather straight NHibernate, but I would think it would be a good starting point.

Comment: I've seen it, but it doesn't help: "Create a separate config file for each database, put them all into a central config folder, and then reference them from the web/app.config"

Comment: Well, I would translate that into creating multiple fluent configs, which create multiple session factories.

Comment: I just read it briefly, but I thought the part most applicable to you was the hash of unique strings stored in the session, that referenced which session factory to use to create the session. I thought that could easily be adapted to your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to edit that after I read some more, but apparently I missed the 5 minute timer.  I actually have already modified my code so that each user gets his/her own SessionFactory upon login.  Except I'm storing it in the HTTP session, not HttpRuntime.Cache.  I imagine that you or someone else will explain to me why this is a bad idea; I haven't messed with this sort of thing in a while.

Comment: Honestly I don't know where the SessionFactory should be stored. My recommendation, though, would be to create a finite number of session factories, which are created at the beginning of the program (similar to how the nhibernate session per request code works). Then, store only a string in each user's session that tells you which session factory to use for their request.